В Linux bash запустить одну и ту же команду с разными параметрами
Положим, мне нужно выполнить за раз несколько похожих команд, что-то вроде
pandoc -o 1.html 1.md ; pandoc -o 2.pdf 1.md ; pandoc -o 3.docx 1.md

Есть ли какой-то способ сократить запись, не дублируя каждый раз одинаковые места в командах?
Условно говоря, написать что-нибудь вроде
pandoc -o [1.html, 2.pdf, 3. docx] 1.md

Чтобы это сработало?

for f in 1.html 2.pdf 3.docx; do pandoc -o $f 1.md; done

Например при помощи вот такой функции:
fun(){
    while [[ $1 ]]; do
        echo $1
        shift
    done
}

$ fun one two three
one
two
three

